# How to display posts with Category named news

Tags: wordpress, categories

I just created a new page template and want to print all posts with category news only.

Used this code based on wordpress codex when it works.

```
<?php
    query_posts( 
        array ( 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'category_name' => 'news', 
            'category' => 1,
            'posts_per_page' => 3 ) 
        );      
        // The Loop

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_title();
            the_content();           
        endwhile;   
        // Reset Query
        wp_reset_query();
?>
```

How can wrap the title into an h1 tag and the content into a div box?

I tried this but it is giving me syntax error:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: Use any one either category_name or category.

Comment: @Kushal Shah I just removed either one and still nothing shows

Comment: you can add like this the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <?php global $post;
    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_type' => 'post',
      'category' => 1
    );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
endforeach; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Comment: Absolutely. Appreciate the support

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove category = 1 in a parameter of the arguments.

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'offset'=> 1,
    'category_name' => 'news'
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
    the_title();
    the_content();

 endforeach; 
 wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Note: Please use slug of category in category_name. Also you have syntax error in

```
<?php the_content(); ?>"> //removed ">
```

Hope this will work for you. Thank you

Comment: Would like to wrap the title in html tag but does not work. Please check my edit

Answer (score 0):

I have added div tag for content & h1 tag for title & updated your code.

Please find your updated code:

```
<?php
    query_posts( 
        array ( 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'category_name' => 'news', 
            'posts_per_page' => 3 
           ) 
        );      
        // The Loop

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <div class="wrap">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;   
        // Reset Query
        wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Hope, this will help you.